# Unable to run jar file from command line

Tags: java, excel, command-line, jar, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet which launches several jar files from the command line. For some reason one of my jars has failed to run from the command line, yet when I double click on the executable, it runs fine.

I need the sheet to be able to run it from the command line. What could the issue be?

Comment: when you try to run it from console, what output do you get? (command should be like this:> java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar)

Comment: When I use java -jar HundredDayUpdate.jar I get "Error: Unable to access jarfile HundredDayUpdate.jar"

Comment: is main class present in your manifest file ?  Here is the sample tutorial for creating executable jars http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/

Comment: When you run the command, are you in the same folder as as HundredDayUpdate.jar ? If not you should run the command like this: java -jar c:\path\to\file\HundredDayUpdate.jar

Comment: I wrote all the Java files. Main class is all in there.

Comment: And I'm running the jar from the same folder as said jar

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe there's something with the Java_HOME? When I run the Jar on my home computer it works fine, but when I login remotely to run the file where it's going to be deployed, it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain steps you need to perform to run jar through command line without specifying main class.

Add  following line to your manifest file , while creating jar.

```
Main-Class : mypackage.myclass.yourclassnamehere
```

Here is the link [  http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/   ] for sample tutorial.

If you want to run from excel file, add java.exe as default program for jar extension executable. (In windows you can do it from control panel or right click on executable and select java.exe from other programs and ticking option as default program for .jar extension)

Comment: Link is not working. But I've written this Jar exactly like the other ones. They all work from the command line.

Comment: Have you added java.exe as default program for jar extension executables.

Comment: I didn't use a manifest file. I exported it to an executable Jar file using Eclipe

Comment: Executable jar through eclipse , adds Main-Class to manifest file .

Comment: I am aware... But what could cause this file to not run from command line, but can run when you double click?

Comment: Also, The issue is not the manifest or in the jar. I just exported the jar with the same code to my own computer and it's working fine.

Comment: Fixed - Apparently there was an issue with the name. I rename the file and the jar works... strange. I'll award you though